# How do I remove the image's SlideShow link?

Tags: picture-library

I want to know how do I remove the image's SlideShow link?

I have this code to customize my Picture SlideShow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SlideshowObjectInitializer() {

 ShowPic = (function(ShowPicOrig) {
  return function() {
       var ssObj = arguments[0];  //SlideShow object
       var curPicIdx=ssObj.index; //current picture index

       //ShowPicOrig.apply(this, arguments); //call original ShowPic

       //apply some changes to display original picture in SlideShow control
       ssObj.image.src = ssObj.linkArray[curPicIdx]; //display original image instead of web image
       //change picture & container size to auto instead of fixed (by default web image size is used)
         ssObj.image.setAttribute('height','100%'); 
         ssObj.image.setAttribute('width','100%'); 
         var cell = ssObj.cell; 
         cell.style.width = 'auto';
         cell.style.height = 'auto';
         cell.style.display = '';
         var pcell = ssObj.cell.parentNode; 
       pcell.style.width = 'auto';
         pcell.style.height = 'auto';

         ssObj.link.href = '';
  };
})(ShowPic);

}  
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(SlideshowObjectInitializer, 'imglib.js');
```

I know that in here: `ssObj.link.href = '';` 
I can put the link that I want, but how do I do so it has any link?

Edit:

I've been looking for this and I discovered that adding `ssObj.link.removeAttribute("href");` I can remove the link.